# How to count black cells without iteration (bitmap?)

Tags: algorithm, function, matrix, bitmap

Been stuck on a problem for a while, hope some of you have ideas.
Given a matrix size N*M of binary values (0 / 1), come with an approach to return the number of 1's which is more efficient than simply iterating the matrix.

The key in my opinion is bitmap. Thought about allocating new N*M matrix and manipulate the two... haven't got a solution yet.

Any ideas?

Comment: Without more information about the structure of the problem, I am pretty sure it is not possible to provide a faster solution than iteration.

Comment: Using an auxiliary array can only slow down the processing.

Comment: It seems to me that you're looking for a binary search algorithm, with complexity O(log n)

Comment: It could be that your system provides efficient matrix vector and dot product operations, so that computing OneN'*A*OneM where A is regarded as a numerical matrix and OneM is a M vector of 1s etc could be (a bit) more efficient than writing loops.

Answer (score 0):

From a theoretical point of view, unless the matrix has special properties, you must test all the N.M elements and this can be achieved by a loop. So this construction is optimal and unbeatable.

In practice, maybe you are looking for a way to get some speedup from a naïve implementation that handles a single element at a time. The answer will be highly dependent on the storage format of the elements and the processor architecture.

If the bits are packed 8 per bytes, you can setup a lookup table of bit counts for every possible byte value. This yields a potential speedup of x8.

---

If you know that the black zone are simply connected (no hole), then it is not necessary to visit their inside, a contouring algorithm will suffice. But you still have to scan the white areas. This allows to break the N.M limit and to reduce to Nw + Lb, where Nw is the number of white pixels, and Lb the length of the black outlines.

If in addition you know that there is a single, simply connected black zone, and you know a black outline pixel, the complexity drops to Lb, which can be significantly smaller than N.M.